# How to create a component to share across websites?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to create a Vue component that has fairly large amount of html/css/js.

The goal is someone should be able to add this component to their website, and without having to write their own duplicate html/css they should see roughly the same on their website as it looks on mine.

I've made a component that I can use on my own website, but how can I make it available to use on other websites? Can people just include a .js file perhaps? But how would they import the html/css into a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare your component so that it can be packaged and published on NPM
maybe this post can help you to achieve that [How To Publish Your Vue.js Component On NPM](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/07/31/vue-component-publish-npm/)